# Set struct field value by condition in struct definition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Reactjs and defining an object as a state to a component.

I want to set a condition for the value of one of the fields right in its defintion. Something like this pseudo code:

```
elementAtts: {
                someField: {someCondition ? 'one' : 'two'}                
             }
```

Is that possible? And if so, what is the correct syntax to do so?

EDIT with an additional question:

I'm trying to use another boolean field of the same struct as a condition:

```
elementAtts: {
                isValid: true,
                someField: isValid ? 'one' : 'two'                
             }
```

When I try to use it like that, I get an error saying that `isValid` is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that possible without `{}` in ternary operator.

> `{someCondition ? 'one' : 'two'}` its a invalid one .

You could do like below

```
elementAtts: {
  someField: someCondition ? 'one' : 'two'
}
```

Comment: If the struct has a boolean field, is it also possible to set the condition to be that field of the same struct?

Comment: I know it wasn't my original question, but is it possible if you could also give an example of other field being used as a condition? When I tried it, I got an error saying that the field is undefined

Comment: @YonatanNir .ok please post a original question of that conditional code

Comment: Edited the question (Or did you mean an entirely new question and you wanted a link?)

Comment: @YonatanNir are you using react ?  `isValid: true,`  that true value where its come from props or manual ?

Comment: It's a field of the struct which is passed to a component and is being updated using a callback. I know I can update that field with the same code, but wanted to check if it's possible to set the condition using that boolean field

Comment: Its  not possible to validate with same object itself. You could set the condition directly on props or else do the condition check on render place https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-cartwright-b0c6l